# How to rsync that excludes .git/ folder but still keep the .git/config file?

Tags: git, rsync

**In brief TLDR**

To rsync a folder that has .git/ excluded but still keeping the .git/config file, how to do that?

My [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+rsync+a+folder+except+.git+folder+but+keep+.git%2Fconfig+file&oq=how+to+rsync+a+folder+except+.git+folder+but+keep+.git%2Fconfig+file&aqs=chrome..69i57.12682j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is not helpful so I asked here.

**Full details**

I want to take snapshot of all of my projects' code into another machine.

Each project code folder is a git-cloned one so they have .git folder.

I don't need those .git so will exclude them.

But I need to know what git repo the projects coming from so need to keep .git/config.

What I tried and didn't work [run it](https://repl.it/@NamG1/rsync-exlude-git-include-gitconfig-NOT-WORKING)

```
rsync -chazvP --dry-run --exclude=".git" --include=".git/config"  $FROM/ $TO/
#             .         .                .                        .      .
```

If you know the correct way to do so, please share.

Comment: Have you tried placing  `--include=...` before `--exclude=...`?

Comment: Not yet, let me try that

Comment: Tried --include before --exclude @danzel and not working.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and tell us _how_ it doesn't work, i.e. the actual result of the commands you tried?

Comment: It can run though the `.git/config` is not kept. I'll find a way to add sample code with shell in repl.it later. Thanks any way.

Comment: @danzel I agree with you that if --include goes after --exclude, my rsync will not working

Comment: @danzel I have updated my question with repl.it sample where we can run and see the result of the command [there](https://repl.it/@NamG1/rsync-exlude-git-include-gitconfig-NOT-WORKING).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1584749/34893)

The idea is **`include` .git/config** and **`exclude` .git/***

```
rsync -chazP  --include '.git/config'  --exclude '.git/*'  "$FROM/" "$TO/"
#     .       include must go first   .                    .        .
```

View detail and run it [here](https://repl.it/@NamG1/rsync-exlude-git-include-gitconfig)